# How to create smpp API to receive smpp request and forward the request to https in laravel?

Tags: sms-gateway, smpp

In our company we have omni channel gateway sending sms to end-users. Our platform could handle http requests but one of our client asking for smpp request as they can send only smpp request. So what should I do to receive that request and forward it to our platform (built on laravel and python) through api.

Comment: Man! I am also searching for such solution. Did you find any ??